# Windows Azure AD with ADFS

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have Office 365 subscription with about 6 users. I need to authorize them to some applications that support ldap authorization. As I understand, I can setup Active Directory Federation Services, connect it to Azure AD and then access ADFS using LDAP. Am I right?

Comment: Could you describe what you mean by ldap authorization? ADFS 2016 (4.0) adds support for authenticating LDAP users, but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot access ADFS externally using LDAP. ADFS accesses AD internally with LDAP.

If an Office 365 wants to use ADFS for authentication, it accesses ADFS through a web service (IIS) running at the ADFS server which is referred as Security Token Service. Then ADFS gets the request, authenticates to AD internally using LDAP and then gives the token back to Office 365.